# System.Json equivalent in Json.Net

Tags: c#

I'm working with some old C# code that uses the following (reader is a StreamReader):

```
JsonValue authorization = JsonValue.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd)
```

`System.Json` no longer used, so what is the code in JSON.net?

Comment: `JValue.Parse()`? I'm not sure what you mean by `System.Json`, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Json.NET there is non generic method that will return `JObject`:

```
JObject item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

You may use generic method if you know json structure:

```
ClassName item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

See Json.NET [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) for more examples

Comment: Thank you.  I assumed the JsonValue item returned a json object, but I wasn't sure of what the json object is in JSON.net